# How to connect a custom domain to an existing subpage/subdomain?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I am trying to connect a custom domain to the subpage of an existing website hosted via Firebase Hosting. Just like in website builder sites who allow users to 'connect a domain'.

Should I connect the new custom domain to Firebase's name servers, and then reroute to the specific subpage?

Or is there a separate standardized approach which lets a website publish content to custom domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot map your DNS records to a subpage because it just map IP addresses to hostname.
The solution for you is to redirect requests from source page to your destination page.